# Where do inputs get their extra width from?

Tags: html, css, layout, calc

I am trying to create a button div and input to all be 80% the width of their container.

However the input is always bigger than 80%.  Why is this?  Do I need to use calc in some way to get it to 80%.

Even when setting the padding to 0px it is still bigger:

https://jsfiddle.net/0rcv1ypb/

```
<input/>
<button></button>
<div></div>


input{
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
}
button{
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  height: 20px;
}
div{
  width: 80%;
  height: 20px;
  background: black;
}
```

As a side question:  the default width for input appears to be 145px.  Where does this value come from as it is not in the agent style sheet.

Answer (score 1):

Because the default browser styling is `box-sizing: content-box`.

Reset it and all elements get the same width as expected, even with different paddings/borders.

```css
* { 
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input{
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
}
button{
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  height: 20px;
}
div{
  width: 80%;
  height: 20px;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<input/>
<button></button>
<div></div>
```

Take a look at the [box-model](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp) and [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/box-sizing/#values).

Comment: Did not know about this property. I just changed the `input` to  `box-sizing: border-box;` and everything lines up now.  I've heard not to use that `*` notation as it is not efficient but who knows.

Comment: Yes, `*` is not the elegant way, but was the easiest for demonstration :). You can also take a look at normalize.css or reset.css -- They helps you to normalize the default browser stylings. But of course you can do this by your own.

Comment: I was reviewing this.  Can you articulate why they have different default values.  I would have never known about this property if this did not happen.

Comment: With out your help I don't think I would have been able to solve this.  As I did not even know https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing existed.